# Is it a common way of interface definition in C

Tags: c

I find a **foo.h** file having:

```
typedef STRUCT_s STRUCT;

STRUCT *foo();
```

and the **foo.c** file:

```
#include "i_foo.h"

struct STRUCT_s{
 //...
};

#define STRUCT struct STRUCT_s
STRUCT *foo()
{
    STRUCT *s;
    //...
    return s;
}
```

Is it the common way to hide the structure definition in C ? If yes, I wonder, if the structure is not declared in the header, how is the client supposed to use it?

Comment: That `#define` is *weird,* not to mention **wrong** (because of the semi-colon). But even when that gets removed, it will remain *weird.*

Comment: I suggest you look into the [pimpl idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer#C) instead of weird hacks like this.

Comment: @Angew Sorry It was my mistake. No semicolon there. It's code of a client. I'not sure if I miss something in C or the code is IOCCC-winner candidate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common way to hide structure definition in C. And client isn't supposed to use structure directly. He has to use only proposed functions from interface to interact with data: instantiate, set or get values, launch operation on it,....

With this way, implementation is totally hidden to client. So client is not constraint by changes in implementation. Library can evolves as it need without disturbing client, according no change in interface.

Comment: OK, good explanation. Unfortunatelly, if there were some functions to operate on STRUCT, I'd be glad. It is a company's shared memory "library". But besides the functions create/destroy/size there is no other function for using the created object. I checked, how they use it in other projects, the other developers define their own structures and cast the returned pointer to their structures. I think, it is not a good way.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz you're right, it's not a good way... with that, a common way (if I don't make mistake) is to add function to library to give among of memory needed by this struct (in `.h` : `size_t sizeofstruct();` and implementation in `.c` with `sizeof(STRUCT)`). With that, you can call allocator with size needed by library, without knowing real structure

Answer (score 3):

The user this way cannot instantiate a structure and only sees objects of this type as pointers. Therefore all the constructors and methods, getters, setters etc. are obscure to the user and should be defined in the library source.

One obvious additional consequence is that if you change the structure, the user does not have to change all its uses in the code to initialize new fields or comment out the uses of defunct ones. Since there were none, and there won't be any. The struct's internal private structure is totally hidden.

Comment: Also, there is no need to recompile the source files using the struct when its implementation changes (encapsulation).

Comment: BTW, does the Standard guarantee it? Do C compilers never use mangling, and are symbols in the bin files guaranteed to look the same as in the source?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the common way to declare an abstract data type (ATD). An ADT is used only through its interface which is represented by the functions declared in the header file. A client doesn't access the fields directly. It's also a good idea to add a prefix to all exported identifiers. This avoids name clashes and makes it clear where an imported identifier comes from.

Example:

Stacks.h

```
typedef struct Stacks_StackDesc *Stacks_Stack;

Stack Stacks_New(void);

void Stacks_Push(int x, Stacks_Stack s);

void Stacks_Pop(Stacks_Stack s, int *top);
```

Stacks.c

```
#include "Stacks.h"

struct Stacks_StackDesc {
   ...
};

Stack Stacks_New(void)
{
   ...
}

void Stacks_Push(int x, Stacks_Stack s)
{
   ...
}

void Stacks_Pop(Stacks_Stack s, int *top)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Prefixes are unlike C++ namespaces in that you cannot `use Stacks;` to make a small scope somewhat shorter. :(